# Eclipse Subversive SVN client not updating local copies with new files

Tags: eclipse, subversive

When I update my local working copy of an SVN repository in Eclipse using the Subversive plugin it isnt bringing any new files which have been added to the SVN repository. It thinks that the local working copy is up to date and if I ask Eclipse to update it it just says no further changes.

Anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried with some other versioned project?  Maybe that particular project has a corrupted svn file?

Comment: @Federico, that is good advice in general, but other people have reported this same problem, and most of them have had no trouble updating the same project/directories with another client.  It seems to be only subversive that ignores these new files.  Either it is caching something it shouldn't, or there is a bug in the libraries it uses to access the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered this nasty problem too.  It might be related to this [bug report.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=302902)

Deleting the entire tree worked for me too, but that hardly seems like a satisfactory solution.  What scares me more is wondering how I will notice that a certain file didn't get updated, if this happens again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the above bug report, this worked for me (eclipse 3.7):

Team/Update to Version...

```
v Update to HEAD revision (=default)

Depth: Full recursive (default is Working copy)
v Change working copy to specified depth (default is un-checked)
O Ignore externals (=default)
v Allow unversioned obstructs (=default)
```

I do not know if that fixes the problem permanently. At least it seems a faster solution rather than full checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have a solution to this problem, but I have it as well, and I don't have enough cred to comment.

Here is a thread describing the same issue: 
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=14710&start=0&

A "workaround" I found to be successful is deleting the relevant tree (of course, backing it up first) and performing an "update". I am prompted to recreate missing files, which bring the un-added files from the repo as well. Obviously this is a terrible solution, but it does work.

Another interesting effect to note is that it is one-sided. The other machine on the repo is perfectly fine with updating new files.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed Subversive to be a bit problematic.  While this isn't a direct solution to your problem, may I recommend using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (assuming you're in Windows). It works excellently, has more power than Subversive, and is integrated with your shell making it a smooth transition.